# Compute autoregressive formula in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I would like to compute a formula on a series, that includes the value of the previous row (or period, in a time series).

To be specific, the formula is `x[i] = b * x[i-1]` except for the first row, which is just `b`. `.shift(1)` is not doing the job because it doesn't change the value.

I used a loop but I am looking for a more elegant version (i.e. a pandas function).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

first = pd.Series(np.arange(0.0,13.0))
b = 0.5
second = pd.Series(b)
for i in range(1, first.shape[0]):
    second[i] = b*second[i-1]

second.head()
#0    0.50000
#1    0.25000
#2    0.12500
#3    0.06250
#4    0.03125
#dtype: float64
```

PS: I didn't know a better word for the problem. If you do, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use starting value as the `base` and raise it to the `power` of range array. This range array would simulate the iterator `i` in `"for i in range(1, first.shape[0]):"`.

Thus, a vectorized approach would be -

```
pd.Series(b**np.arange(1,first.shape[0]+1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `pd.Series(b**first)`? After all, it is not guaranteed that the numbers are increasing by `1` for the length of my vector.

Comment: @MERose Well based on the code posted in the question, you are just using the shape param for creating the array `second` at : `for i in range(1, first.shape[0]):`. So, no, it won't be `pd.Series(b**first)`. If it is not guaranteed that the numbers are increasing by 1 for the length of your vector, please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: That's just example data which happen to be increasing by 1. To generalise your answer it's not necessary to edit the question.